# Only putting part of a set to an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, set

I have a list of soccer players that are in an array of 33 called "players". They all have different stats, and I created a comparator that compares those stats. What I'd like to do is create two separate arrays that gets the top 11 players, and the bottom 11 players. I'm then able to do different calculations based on those. Here's what I have:

```
    Set<Player> ascending = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    Collections.addAll(ascending, players);
    Player[] sorted = ascending.toArray(new Player[ascending.size()]);
    Player[] topEleven = new Player[11];
    Player[] bottomEleven = new Player[11];
    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        topEleven[i]=sorted[i];
    }
    for(int i=0,j=32;i<11;i++,j--){
        bottomEleven[i]=sorted[j];
    }
```

This works, however it's clunky and probably not very efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet(E,%20boolean) and 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet(E)

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you to use arrays instead of `java.util.List`? If not I'd suggest to use List instead as you save some conversion logic and Lists come with a lot of convenience methods that will make your life easier.

Comment: @dpr : Yes, I keep the player list very organized, and move players around a lot. The selection process is used by the specific location in the array (ie, players[12]). To my knowledge, this isn't possible with lists. But I could be wrong!

Comment: @ShaddAnderson either I'm missing your point or you are missing the method `java.util.List.get(n)`. Maybe you are confusing this with `java.util.Set` which don't provide the possibility to access elements by index. Actually the only situation where I'm using arrays instead of List are [vararg methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the `Arrays.copyOfRange` method like so:

```
Set<Player> ascending = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
Set<Player> descending = new TreeSet<>(comparator.reversed());
Collections.addAll(ascending, players);
Collections.addAll(descending, players);
Player[] topEleven = Arrays.copyOfRange(ascending.toArray(), 0, 10);
Player[] bottomEleven = Arrays.copyOfRange(descending.toArray(), 0, 10);
```

Or like @drp said, you can use the `subList` method on List objects.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can use streams:

```
Player[] topEleven = ascending.stream().limit(11).toArray(Player[]::new);
```

Also, you can use streams for sorting since it won't modify the original `players`:

```
Player[] topEleven = players.stream()
                            .sorted(comparator)
                            .limit(11)
                            .toArray(Player[]::new);
```

Comment: This is the exact efficiency I'm looking for. I just haven't gotten much into streams. I'll definitely have to check them out, though. Makes everything seem much more quick and easy.

Comment: It won't probably matter in your case, but Java8 streams are not considered to be efficient/quick compared to the "usual" way of processing collections.

Comment: @dpr: The speed loss is negligible by an array of 33 players, while the increase in code readability and simplicity is enorm. Also, comparing to your solution, there is no loss at all since set to stream conversion is equivalent to `Collections.addAll`, while both solutions sort and create an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, if you want to stick with `Set`:

```
final Player[] topEleven = new Player[11];
System.arraycopy(ascending.toArray(new Player[ascending.size()]), 0, topEleven,
    0, topEleven.length);

final Player[] bottomEleven = new Player[11];
System.arraycopy(descending.toArray(new Player[descending.size()]), 0, bottomEleven,
    0, bottomEleven.length);
```

Or you could switch to using `List` and do this:

```
List<Player> ascending = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(ascending, players);
ascending.sort(comparator)
Player[] topEleven = ascending.subList(0, 10).toArray(new Player[11]);
```